# How to find collisions in a hash function knowing its coefficent?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Say I have a simple hash function where $x$ is a sequence of integers:

$$h(x)=(a_1\cdot x_1+...+ a_n\cdot x_n) \bmod N=\sum_i a_i\cdot x_i \bmod N$$

where $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n$ is the coefficient known to the attacker,
size of $x$ can be anything smaller than $N$.

How to find 2 different inputs that hashes to the same value, i.e $0$?

I feel like this has something to do with linear combination / euclid algorithm but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can easily find collisions for this system.

Let $x=(x_1,...,x_n) $ be a sequence such that $h(x)=k$. For finding collision we can do this:

Select $x'=(x_1',...,x_{n-1}')$ and then compute:

> $$x_n'=({a_n}^{-1}\cdot(k-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_ix_i')) \bmod N$$

Now we have  $h(x)=h(x')=k$.

Comment: Just curious, is there any way to make the last bit xn' to be within an arbitrary range? say between 0-100.

Comment: @LoveProgramming, Yes, first choose $x_n$ in your range, and then compute $x_{n-1}$ using my method.

Comment: Can I make every Xi to be within arbitrary range?

Comment: @LoveProgramming, This is evident that at most one $x_i$ can not be within arbitrary range.